# Query para não repetir um valor já cadastrado

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Estou com a seguinte situação:

Preciso fazer uma query SQL em um campo para retornar somente as viaturas que estão cadastradas em um formulário (tabela viaturas) e que o formulário `despachos_ocorrencias` as viaturas que já foram “escolhidas” não apareçam no campo viatura deste formulário. Porém estão aparecendo todas, eu não consigo por exemplo, fazer com que este meu `SELECT` ignore a viatura que já foi escolhida no formulário `despacho_ocorrencias` (tabela `despacho_ocorrencias`).

Por exemplo, tenho a viatura 24, 56, 50 e 70 cadastradas no formulário de viaturas, eu tenho a viatura 24 já escolhida (registro cadastrado na tabela de `despacho_ocorrencias`), quando eu for cadastrar um novo registro no formulário aparecem todas as viaturas 24, 56, 50 e 70 em vez de aparecer somente as 56, 50 e 70. Eu queria que a 24 não aparecesse porque ela já está escolhida para um `despacho_ocorrencia`.

Fiz meu SQL assim.

```
Select distinct viaturas.vtr_numero
  From viaturas, despacho_ocorrencias
 Where despacho_ocorrencias.vtr_atendimento = viaturas.vtr_numero and 
       viaturas.parado_manutencao=‘NÃO’ and 
       viaturas.parado_utilizacao=‘NÃO’ and 
       despacho_ocorrencias.fechar_despacho!=“1”
```

OBS: este “1” é um flag despacho fechado.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Seria melhor se você desse um exemplo prático com dados de entrada e dados de saída, de preferência usando um `fiddle`, como um [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você quer aqueles números de veículo que existem em viaturas mas não estão cadastrados em despacho_ocorrencias. Tente:

```
Select distinct viaturas.vtr_numero
  From viaturas
 Where NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM despacho_ocorrencias WHERE despacho_ocorrencias.vtr_atendimento = viaturas.vtr_numero) and 
       viaturas.parado_manutencao=‘NÃO’ and 
       viaturas.parado_utilizacao=‘NÃO’ and 
       despacho_ocorrencias.fechar_despacho!=“1”
```